# Where to put S3 secret when deploying using Appveyor?

Tags: amazon-s3, appveyor

I've got an Appveyor project setup and working awesomely. Now, I want to upload artifacts S3 for easy hosting. This seems fairly easy as outlined in [the documentation](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/amazon-s3/). My question is, where do I put the secret with write permission? I don't want to push it to my public repo for obvious reasons. On travis I could put it in an environment variable that was never logged. How would I go about this in Appveyor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to store this in YAML. You can use [secure variables](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables). Or you can simple put your secrets in clear text to S3 deployment configuration in UI, then save and press `Export YAML` and you will have YAML section with secrets encrypted.